# Scala parsing string sequence

Tags: scala

I wish to parse a sequence of string into individual tokens. Right now it only parses the first word.

```
class SimpleRegexParser extends RegexParsers{

 def word: Parser[String]    = """[a-z]+""".r ^^ { _.toString }

}

object SimpleRegexParserMain extends SimpleRegexParser{
 def main(args: Array[String]) = {
println(parse(word, "johnny has a little lamb"))

 }
}
```

Right now I am getting : **[1.7] parsed: johnny**

How can I parse the whole string into individual tokens, so that this works for variable string length.

Any pointers to make this work are welcome. Please tell me how I can make it work in scala.

Comment: How can I filter our words in upper case? Tried changing the definition to """[A-Z]+""".r, but it only matches the first word for string "LABEL text to be printed AND will be used for &&"

Comment: In Java this code works: 'public class RegexExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "LABEL text to be printed AND will be used for &&";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
  }
}'  how can I get the same result in scala?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found the answer to this.

I had to change the definition of word.

Here is the updated definition:

```
class SimpleRegexParser extends RegexParsers{

def word: Parser[String]    = rep("""[a-z]+""".r) ^^ { _.toString }

}
```

Previous expression was working for single word, I now have a repetition of word **rep()**.

Here is the result:

```
[1.25] parsed: List(johnny, has, a, little, lamb)
```

Comment: val regexPattern = """[a-z]+""".r
regexPattern.findAllIn("johnny has a little lamb").foreach { println }

even this would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I have to filter strings in upper case, what should I change?

Comment: """[A-Z]+""".r . this regex would filter strings which are upper case.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and get back.

Comment: I updated my code to:  def word: Parser[String]    = rep("""[A-Z]+""".r) ^^ { _.toString }.  My input string is "STARTQUOTE johnny has a little lamb ENDQUOTE". The result I get is: [1.11] parsed: List(STARTQUOTE).  It is missing the second upper case word.